# DecisionTreeClassifier with torch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to use a Decision Tree with data from audio. I get this Torch.Tensor for X_train :

```
[tensor([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11,  0,  0, 28,  0,  0, 11,  0,  0, 20,
       0,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 15,  0,  0,  0,  0,  4,  4,  0, 21,  0,
       9,  0,  9,  0,  0,  0,  7,  0,  0, 25, 15, 15, 21,  0, 20,  7, 18,  0,
       0, 18, 31,  4,  4, 13,  0, 11,  0, 26,  0,  4,  4, 26, 14,  0, 11,  4,
       0, 19,  0, 21,  0, 20,  0,  0, 10,  0,  7,  0,  0, 31,  0,  4,  4,  0,
       8,  0, 18, 27, 27, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 25,  0,
       0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  4]]),
tensor([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10, 21,  0, 20, 20,  5, 26, 26,  0,  4,  4,
       0,  0,  7,  0,  0, 25,  0, 17,  4,  4, 19, 19, 11,  4,  4, 26, 21, 21,
       4,  0,  9,  0,  0,  7,  0, 24,  0,  0, 24,  0, 31,  4,  4,  7, 20,  0,
       4,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7,  0, 27,  0,  0,  0, 18,  0,  0, 31,  0,  0,
       4,  4,  0, 24, 24,  0,  0,  7,  0,  0,  0,  0, 13,  0,  0,  0,  4, 18,
      18, 15, 15,  0,  0, 17,  0, 11,  4,  4,  0, 26, 14, 14,  0,  0,  7,  0,
       0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 26,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  4]]),
tensor([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 25, 25, 14, 21,  0, 27, 18, 10,  4,  4,
      16,  0,  0, 15,  0,  0,  0, 24,  0,  0,  7,  0,  0,  0, 12,  0,  0,  0,
       4,  8,  0,  0, 11,  0,  4,  0, 17,  0,  0, 11,  0,  0, 22,  0,  0, 26,
       0,  4,  0, 15, 20,  0,  4,  4,  4,  0, 25,  0,  0,  0, 19,  0,  0,  0,
       0,  7, 18,  0,  0, 18,  0,  4,  0, 32, 21, 21,  0, 21,  0,  0,  0,  0,
       0,  0,  0, 25, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  4]]), .......
```

And this series for y_train:

```
12    M
16    M
10    M
9     F
```

When I apply the decision tree I have problems with X_train:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

for i in range(0,3):
    Xtrain = X_train[i][0]
    Ytrain = y_train[i]
    clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
    clf.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain)


ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 11.  0.  0. 28.  0.  0. 11.  0.  0. 20.
  0.  4.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 15.  0.  0.  0.  0.  4.  4.  0. 21.  0.
  9.  0.  9.  0.  0.  0.  7.  0.  0. 25. 15. 15. 21.  0. 20.  7. 18.  0.
  0. 18. 31.  4.  4. 13.  0. 11.  0. 26.  0.  4.  4. 26. 14.  0. 11.  4.
  0. 19.  0. 21.  0. 20.  0.  0. 10.  0.  7.  0.  0. 31.  0.  4.  4.  0.
  8.  0. 18. 27. 27. 11.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 25.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  4.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Please give the complete code. It's currently unclear where `DecisionTreeClassfier` comes from.

Comment: Your code still doesn't say where `DecisionTreeClassifier` is defined... If it's imported then please put the import statement too.

Comment: oh yes! from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
sorry I edit the question too

Comment: OK. Then maybe try `Xtrain = X_train[i]`?